# I have set access-control-allow-origin to *, but doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

In my node.js server, I wrote:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With","Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS"});
```

And through POSTMan in chrome, I can receive:

```
access-control-allow-headers → X-Requested-With
access-control-allow-methods → PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin → *
```

But if I try to access the url in my javascript, I still get warning:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://somedomain/login. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I tested this on my localhost so the Origin is null. I've also tested on my server(another domain), not work.

So how could I successfully send a cross domain request?

Comment: Odds are that you are only sending out those headers when you respond to a POST request and that you haven't written a handler specifically for the preflight OPTIONS request that the error message mentions at all.

Comment: @Quentin I'm new to node.js. How do I set the preflight OPTION request? It's a POST request sent from JavaScript after all...

Comment: It isn't a POST request. It is an OPTIONS request. The POST request will come later after you've told the browser it is OK to make it.

Comment: How you respond to an OPTIONS request depends on what HTTP library you are using (you haven't told us that or shown us enough code for us to guess).

Comment: the origin is null? are you loading the html from the filesystem? if yes... then that is the reason for the problem.